# Should questions be marked as duplicates of closed or otherwise disabled questions?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, duplicate-questions

I recently answered a question on SO that was marked as a duplicate:

[Selecting specific rows of a matrix in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076435/selecting-specific-rows-of-a-matrix-in-matlab)

However, the question was marked as a duplicate of another question. No problem, except that the question in question is closed:

[Extract rows from matrix and make a new matrix in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018057/extract-rows-from-matrix-and-make-a-new-matrix-in-matlab)

In this case, I suppose the askers already got most of the information they need, and additional answers might not help too much. But in general, this seems like a bad idea, because both of the questions are disabled in some way, so no one will be able to interact with either of them. If someone came upon these questions and had a better suggestion, they wouldn't be able to post on either question.

Isn't that a suboptimal situation?

Comment: It is marked at "too localized", and shouldn't have been.  I cast the first vote to reopen.  Since it wasn't marked as dupe, I have no way of looking at the other referenced questions.

Comment: @AndrewMao yes. I've missunderstood the problem. Deleted the comment.

Comment: @LanceRoberts Pretty much a zero-effort question though. If not "too localized" then perhaps NARQ.

Comment: @Bart, yeh, a little googling would have gone a long way.  But I think it's good for SO to have basic questions like that, so that future googlers would be led here.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I linked to the wrong question. Posted both links now. But I think that even that question could have had a good answer about the various ways to index matrices in MATLAB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a question is closed as a duplicate of a question that is also closed then one of the two things is true:

1. The recent question could also be closed for whatever reason the duplicate target was closed.  Would you rather see your question closed as not a real question, or as a duplicate of a question that is not a real question?  Either way, your question should be closed, it's simply a matter of which helps explain why it should be closed better.  By closing as a duplicate it's possible to get some helpful information from the old thread, such as explanations as to why the question was closed, or even helpful information in comments/answers that will help to find a solution.
2. The question really isn't a duplicate, because the recent question shouldn't also be closed for the same reason as the duplicate target.  If this is the case then the recent question should be re-opened because it's not actually a duplicate (if the new question has addressed whatever issue caused the older question to be closed).